# How can I initialize a class that was dynamically loaded with a custom class loader?

Tags: java, classloader, static-initialization

Suppose I have a class that is loaded using a custom class loader

```
Class<?> clz = myClassLoader.loadClass("classLoaders.Test");
```

How can I initialize the class (run its static initializers) without creating an instance, knowing its members, or using reflection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make sure a class is initialized, call [`Class.forName(String name, boolean initialize, ClassLoader loader)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName-java.lang.String-boolean-java.lang.ClassLoader-) with a `true` value for the `initialize` parameter.

```
Class<?> clz = Class.forName("classLoaders.Test", true, myClassLoader);
```